# Moodle CAS authentication and custom profile fields

Tags: moodle, cas, autofill

I need to authenticate against a CAS server and once the process is successful, I would like to autoregister and fill in certain custom fields in my profile with the data/attributes provided by the CAS server. Have you ever had any kind of experience? Do the fields get autofilled?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it already does that.

Create a user profile field.

Then go to the CAS config via Site admin > Plugins > Authentication CAS server (SSO)

Or direct to `/admin/auth_config.php?auth=cas`

Scroll down for the custom fields. Then enter the attribute name from the SSO and for "Update local" either choose "On creation" or "On every login"

See https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Managing_authentication#Profile_fields_data_mapping_and_locking